Medication use as a time dependent covariate in cox regression?
The goal is to assess how the use of 3 drugs affects the risk of an event.
We are using real-life observational data and as such the medications may change during the follow-up time. I am looking for some statistical technique to handle these changes and account for initiation of a drug and stopping another or using some at the same time etc.
I have thought about several approaches and using these medications as a time dependent covariate in a cox regression seems reasonable to me.
The way I am thinking about it is to have multiple rows per patient where each row represents a period where there is no change in the covariates.
I have tried to simulate some data in R :
library(survival)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)


n <- 500

patient_data <- data.frame(
  PatientID = rep(1:n, each = 5),  
  Age = sample(40:80, n, replace = TRUE),
  Sex = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  Time = rep(0, n * 5),  
  drugA = sample(0:1, n * 5, replace = TRUE),
  drugB = sample(0:1, n * 5, replace = TRUE),
  drugC = sample(0:1, n * 5, replace = TRUE),
  Event = rep(0, n * 5)  
)


for (i in 1:n) {
  follow_up_time <- sample(1:10, 5, replace = TRUE)  
  patient_data$Time[(i - 1) * 5 + 1:(length(follow_up_time))] <- cumsum(follow_up_time)
  patient_data$Event[(i - 1) * 5 + 1:(length(follow_up_time))] <- rbinom(length(follow_up_time), 1, pmin(0.1 * follow_up_time, 0.5))
}

surv_object <- with(patient_data, Surv(Time, Event))

cox_model <- coxph(surv_object ~ Age + Sex + drugA + drugB + drugC + cluster(PatientID) , data = patient_data, id = PatientID)


summary(cox_model)


Additionally, in the simulated data I have also included multiple events per patient as the event is stroke and it could be recurrent.
Is this a valid approach?
Is there something obvious I am not thinking about?
I am not an expert in statistics in any way so I am just trying to figure this out.
Any plotting suggestions for these covariates?
Any other suggestion of other methods (even if they are complex) is welcomed.
P.S I am thinking of adding competing risk of death later on and I was also wondering if it is possible.

Yes, that's definitely a reasonable way to do this, and a fairly common one.
Plotting depends on your sample size, but it's useful to do some graphs showing individual trajectories on and off treatment.  I might do these with lines connecting the observed points rather than with the step functions you use in the analysis, just because that makes it easier to see the changes.

Thanks for your reply! Can you tell me if the multiple events would work is it better to just censor the subject after the first event?
Sample sizes is in the 10s of thousands so individual trajectories would not work.
To my understanding from the results I will be taking a single coefficient (and HRs) for each covariate, even if they are time dependent, so using these could I do a simple cumulative survival plot with lines seperated for each drug and perhaps a simple forrest plot for significance of hazard ratios?

You get more information from using all the events, but not hugely more. I'd be inclined to use all the data. People often censor after the first event but that's either because they really think the first event is different or because they learned survival analysis before recurrent event methods were readily available. You can still do a nice simple forest plot with recurrent events, but you can't do a cumulative survival plot in any simple way, so that's an argument for first-event models.

While this is a fairly common approach, its validity is dependent on what it is you are actually trying to estimate and on the assumptions you are willing to make.
From your somewhat vague description I am guessing that you are interested in some sort of causal effect. Since all of your variables of interest vary over time, there are many causal effects you could be interested in. These are called treatment regimes. For example you could be interested in what would happen if everyone always got drug $A$ for the entire timeframe of interest. This would be a static treatment regime. You could also be interested in more dynamic treatment regimes, such as: "use drug $A$ only if a person previously had a stroke, then always use it" or something similar. Therefore, the first thing you need to do is be crystal clear about what it is that you actually want to know. Only then does it make sense to think about the analysis.
Next you will need to think about the causal process that generated your data in the first place. There was no randomization envolved as far as I can tell from your description, so you will probably need to take care of confounding somehow. The problem is that this is not so easily done with time-varying treatments + confounders, due to something called treatment confounder feedback (see https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwaa243 for an explanation). If this is likely to be a problem, the simple approach of using a Cox model with time-dependent covariates will not be a valid approach, even if all modeling assumptions for the Cox model hold.
Stuff like marginal structural models (https://doi.org/10.2188%2Fjea.JE20200226) may be needed to answer your question fully in these cases. These kind of models are pretty complex though, so getting some sort of formal statistical consulting might be your best bet.

Thank you for this reply! This is really interesting info indeed, and that makes me wonder: as most treatment selections are in fact based on other time-varying confounders, which are also affected by the treatment, most observational studies (that are carried out with simpler approaches) with real-life data on medications are in fact affected by treatment confounder feedback.
